# To avoid creation of std::shared_ptr from raw pointers?

Tags: pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am currently following the book **Effective Modern C++" and it says

> Avoid creating std::shared_ptrs from variables of raw pointer type.

And I am convinced with the explanation so that I, too, agree on that we need to avoid. But there is an exception I encountered.

```
class Person
{
protected:
    Person();
public:

    static std::shared_ptr<Person> getShared()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Person>(new Person());
    }
```

When we hide the default constructor `std::make_shared` cannot do its job. That's why I use a static method in the example above. My question is

1. Is this best I can do about the situation?
2. I still use raw pointer to create a `shared_ptr`, but in this case I can predict what may happen to this pointer. Does this practice still threaten my code?

Comment: Of course you can't create a `std::shared_ptr` object without passing in a raw pointer, what the book says is that you should avoid creating the share pointers from pointer variables. It's right there in the quote even. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are supposed to use `make_shared` to avoid passing a raw pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `auto i = make_shared<int>(42);` No raw pointer passed anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: On a related note, you might want to read about [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: Well obviously I'm not talking about `make_shared`, but the OP in his second question says that a raw pointer is used, and that's true. You can't create a `shared_ptr` object the way the OP is doing without passing a pointer. `make_shared` is nice in that it hides the creation of the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this might not be the best way to do that, one way to do get your constructor protected to a certain degree but still make it callable by `std::make_shared` is the following:

```
class MyClass
{
protected:
    struct ConstructorGuard {};

public:
    MyClass(ConstructorGuard g) {}

    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> create()
    {
         return std::make_shared<MyClass>(ConstructorGuard());
    }
};
```

The constructor itself is public, but it cannot be called from outside the class, because it requires an argument of type `ConstructorGuard` which is a protected nested class, such that only the class itself (and the derived classes) can construct such an object to pass it to the constructor.

Comment: That is actually an interesting solution. It works, client gets a little confused, though. But I will still accept the answer.